# How can I remove HTML using Ruby regular expressions?

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to remove everything contained within two HTML tags, as well as the tags themselves, using regular expressions in Ruby. Here's an example:

```
<tag>a bunch of stuff between the tags, no matter what it is</tag>
```

Basically, I want to use `gsub!` to filter all instances of this type out, like so:

```
text_file_contents.gsub!(/appropriate regex/, '')
```

What would be a good Ruby regular expression for doing so?

Comment: Use [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) when you have HTML/XML in your dish to digest it safely..

Comment: [You can't parse HTML with RegExp!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/838733)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As has been said in the comments [use an html parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). If, however, you just want to remove everything between two tags and don't care about nesting (e.g. if you have `<tag><tag></tag></tag>`) then you can simply use:

```
text_file_contents.gsub!(/<tag>.*?<\/tag>/, '')
```

But again this is flaky. [Nokogiri is really easy to use](http://nokogiri.org/) and will be a lot more stable, please use that.

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::XML(yourfile)
doc.search('//tag').each do |node|
  node.remove
end
```

Comment: Forward slashes must be escaped right ? text_file_contents.gsub!(/<tag>.*?<\/tag>/, '')

Comment: you're right. Thanks @praaveen. I've edited to fix that line. (main point is not to use a regex to parse html though!)